# Kubernetes Percentage Used of a Volume with Metricbeat

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, metricbeat

I am using metricbeat to gather metrics about my k8s cluster and the pods running within it. I would like to setup alerting for my PVCs and to that end I need to know the percentage of a PVC that is used.

From metricbeat I am getting data regarding volumes and their total capacity, amount used... however there is no field for the percentage used.

I have seen articles where I can use the visual builder to 'compute' the percentage but I am not sure that helps me with alerts. It seems that I need a field with the value of percentage used.

I cannot find a way to configure metricbeat to create a new field for the percentage used. It does seem there is an option using a scripted field but this seems to carry performance implications.

1. How can I setup alerts for percentage used of k8s volumes?
2. What is the best way to get an index field for percentage used of a volume?

Comment: What version of kubernetes You use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two options that I found:

1. [Scripted fields in Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/scripted-fields.html)
2. Update Logstash Indexer to do the computation and add a field to the index

I ultimately went with #2 and added a [ruby filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html#plugins-filters-ruby-add_field) to my indexer config to compute the field and add it.

```
filter {
  ruby {
     code => ' total = event.get("[kubernetes][volume][fs][capacity][bytes]");
            if (total != nil)
               used = event.get("[kubernetes][volume][fs][used][bytes]");
               percentUsed = (used.to_f / total)
               event.set("kubernetes.volume.fs.percentage.used", percentUsed)
            end'
  }
```

}

I selected #2 because I did not want to burden Kibana and I had more capacity on the indexers.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use `kubernetes.volume.fs.used.pct`.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/exported-fields-kubernetes.html

Comment: Thanks I believe this is added in more recent versions of elastic but I would suggest this over my answer where available.